# Tiles or Grid as default view ? (for files)

Tags: information-architecture, grid, files, information-design

Are there any statistics on whether users use more often list/tiles view in their file drives? e.g file explorer, mac finder, G-drive, Drop-box, OneDrive...

I know the value of each display but want to decide on the default view

Comment: I personally use list/detail view in most applications as I find a single direction a lot easier to parse and it can easily show a lot more information in one go. Grids with previews of the file content are only really good when you don't know the filename but you know what the contents look like and the contents are sufficiently unique when displayed at thumbnail size.

Comment: Not that I know but typically lists are more usable if you go searching something by date, name or extension. Further grid are more expensive in terms of viewport space available.